# Changing the billing address on order informations page only closes payment information box?

Tags: commerce

On order information page during checkout process in “Payment information” block I see checkbox “My billing information is the same as my shipping information.” and it’s checked when page is opened first time. If I uncheck it I get drop-down for selecting some other address from address book or creating new one. But what ever option I choose from that drop-down  block just closes again and checkbox becomes checked again?!?

Is that normal behavior or it's is a bug? Should the block stay open if different address is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug is fixed in latest module version (Commerce Shipping 8.x-2.0-rc2).

Comment: Rule of thumb, when you have a bug, update to the latest version and see if its still there.

Comment: Agree but I asked this on September and version with bug-fix was released on October...